# Images from my flowdocument to fixeddocument conversion lost appearing

Tags: c#, xps

I found a FlowDocument conversion that passes to XPS and then puts it in my FixedDocument so I can view and print it, it was working perfectly. But now the images no longer appear in the print what could it be?

Thanks in advance for all the help.

```
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument(); //FlowDocument with a image

var paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)doc).DocumentPaginator;
var package = Package.Open(new MemoryStream(), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
var packUri = new Uri("pack://temp.xps");
PackageStore.RemovePackage(packUri);
PackageStore.AddPackage(packUri, package);
var xps = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.NotCompressed, packUri.ToString());
XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xps).Write(paginator);
FixedDocument TESTE = xps.GetFixedDocumentSequence().References[0].GetDocument(true);
```

Comment: I was using Flowdocument with images for a while, but it seems a recent Windows update/patch cause the problem.... I'll keep you updated if I found any solution/alternative

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft publish a workaround for this issue :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5022083-change-in-how-wpf-based-applications-render-xps-documents-a4ae4fa4-bc58-4c37-acdd-5eebc4e34556